# Small SOT-23 transistor markings

Tags: components, surface-mount, markings

I've got a SOT-23 transistor (I think, but it could also be an IC) marked with 1E. Another one is marked with A7W. Then I can also see WR5. How are you supposed to decode these?

Comment: Do you know the manufacturer?

Comment: No idea on the manufacturer.

Comment: You can get some choices but it's hard to know for sure. 3 letters at 34 choices (I/1 and O/0 are too close) = "only" 39304 different parts, and I doubt there are fewer than 39304 different SOT-23 parts.

Comment: Pls, whitch transistor has marking 3DG? (SOT 23, NPN, propably 400Vc-e)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the "[SMD code book](http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/mainframe.htm)" or get the actual schematic or package for the device, but there may not really be a clear way to identify many SMD parts from the surface.

1E for example might be a plain BC847A according to the list.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late reaction, so I guess you've found out by now, but for completeness:

**WR5** in SOT23 = **BZX84-B6V2**, 6.2V zener, by Philips

**A7W** in SOT23 = **BAV99**, dual diode, by Philips

**1E** in SOT23 = probably **BC847A**, NPN transistor, by Philips, but may also be either:
CM9NB847A, NPN transistor, by Canaan Microelectronics
FMMTA43, NPN transistor, by Zetex
KST43, NPN transistor, by Samsung
MMBTA43, NPN transistor, by ITT
R3131N29EC3, Vdet-IC 2.9V, by Ricoh
SMBTA43, NPN transistor, by Infineon
TMPTA43, NPN transistor, by Allegro

All found in the [SMD databook 2011](http://turuta.md/smd2011.html), 2500 comprehensive pages. Recommended.

Comment: Hmm, all the 43's look like drop-in replacements, and same with the 847A's.

Comment: @Mike - yes, I thought they might be, but I didn't go and check the datasheets. That's why I list them as they appeared in the book. And highlighted the BC847, because that's a common one.

Comment: The 2010 version of the data book can be downloaded for free [here](http://www.turuta.md/BOOKARCHIVE/SMD-2010.pdf).

Comment: @FedericoRusso (and all who are about to click): 404 by now.

Answer (score 4):

The A7W is a [double diode](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd-files/pdf/b/bav99_p.pdf).  I took a guess and googled "transistor marking A7W".  Good luck on the rest.

[Here's a PDF that shows the markings for SMD Philips chips](http://matthieu.benoit.free.fr/cross/competitive/philips/SMD-PHILIPS.pdf).  Most are standard parts, so then you can look up a real datasheet.