# Hit a dead end with SMD componet

Tags: transistors, identification

Hello I am fairly new to fixing electronics I have this old mechanical keyboard from Cooler Master that I am refurbishing, I have searched and searched I reached out to cooler master about getting a schematic or help they blew me off and closed my ticket.  The missing part was labeled  A 1 1 Z, There is also the same component by one of the LEDS, I cant figure out if its a mosfet or a transistor I have been testing it with my multi meter and have been getting a bunch of different readings.  I have read a views guide and watched some videos on how to identify what the component is but none of my readings match what they say. Sorry if my info is not very good I'm still trying to learn.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Readings where taken from the intact component, it is the same as the missing one.

Comment: How do you know the component is missing as opposed to non-populated? Although the solder pads do not appear particularly clean (the image is low-resolution), there does not appear to be any sign of a failed or blown component.

Comment: How did the component "go missing"? Did you tear it off? Was it really there before? In your photo, it looks like the pads don't have solder on them, so it looks like it was there. Can't see any A11Z, but 11Z would be a Zener diode, A11 is some diode as well.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/6108/2028

Comment: Could that be A3401  
https://www.s-manuals.com/smd/a1  
https://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/a/o/ao3401_ao.pdf

Comment: @JYelton  I pulled it off, had it in tweezers testing it  and it shot across the my room.

Comment: @Skko Ah, I hate it when that happens. So you're sure that it had the same markings as the ones still on the board? I wasn't able to find something that matched, but just wanted to clarify.

Comment: @JYelton yup, it had the same marking as the other one.